# sql ORDER in message format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Messages icon, which on click opens a facebook-like messaging `div`. The `div` is automatically scrolled to the bottom. On this `div`, I get the last 25 Messages. The problem is that I want the messages to order from the most recent at the bottom of the `div`. I have two order columns: ***id*** which is auto increment and ***dt*** which is a datetime.

I've tried every combination of ORDER BY and I can't get it.

```
SELECT TOP 25 
    rec, 
    sender, 
    message, 
    CONVERT(varchar(20),dt,120) AS date 
FROM dbo.messages 
WHERE (rec='$user[name]' OR sender='$user[name]') 
ORDER BY id DESC, dt ASC
```

There is no bottom, but `SELECT BOTTOM 25 * ORDER BY id` would work perfect, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just order by the datetime column (descending), then pull the top 25. I've modified your query.

```
SELECT TOP 25 
rec, sender, message, CONVERT(varchar(20),dt,120) AS date 
FROM dbo.messages
WHERE (rec='$user[name]' OR sender='$user[name]') 
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Comment: That retrieves the last 25 results but the problem is that when I loop through, the latest message shows at the top since it's the first result, and towards the INPUT Box for answering, shows the last result of the query. I want the last 25 records, ordered by ID/DT ASC.

Comment: So why don't you just handle flipping the order in the application layer? This seems like it's a display issue more than a query issue. And that isn't to say SQL Server couldn't handle it, it's just that your app could handle it better/quicker.

Comment: And you're assuming that your IDs and your datetimes will always be in the correct order. They need not necessarily be. Even taking in the data by date DESC then flipping that should allow for the proper order instead of relying on an arbitrary ID field.

Comment: I ended up reversing the array. Seemed like a more logical answer. Thx Matt

Comment: Cool, glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `SELECT BOTTOM 25 * ORDER BY id`  (ie; `TOP 25 ORDER BY id DESC`)

```
;with cte as (
  select top 25 
        id,
        rec, 
        sender, 
        message, 
        dt
  from dbo.messages 
  where (rec='$user[name]' OR sender='$user[name]') 
  order by id desc
)
select rec, sender, message, convert(varchar(20),dt,120) date
from cte
order by id,dt -- as required here
```